# How to Insert a Null Character (ASCII 00) in Notepad?

Tags: windows, notepad

I want to insert a null character (ASCII Value 00) into an open file in Notepad. A program that is reading this file is expecting 00 at the end, but it's getting the ASCII value for space - 20.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I had hoped that holding Alt and pressing four zero on the numpad would insert the null the same way it inserts all of the fÜn printable characters but it doesn't.

Comment: If it did work, you'd only need *two* zeros, not four. `Alt+09` works for Tab, for example.

Answer (score 30):

This is not possible to do with Notepad, however, it can be done with a more advanced editor.

### With Notepad++

1. Go to `Edit > Character Panel` to show the ASCII Insertion Panel.
2. Put the cursor where you want to insert the character.
3. Double-click the character (in the Character column) to insert.

   [image: ASCII Insertion Panel]

Comment: @DavidPostill It's Notepad++, which is actually what I was searching for when I found this question.

Comment: That doesn't help when the OP us using Notepad.

Comment: @DavidPostill This isn't *for* the OP anymore. This is for users who find this question when searching. The OP got what he wanted years ago and deleted his account. Besides, [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/167309/494173) is also Notepad++

Comment: I found that this does not work if it is the start of a new line; have to type something and then double-click NULL, and then erase the first thing. Just some bug in Notepad++.

Comment: @Abacus It works for me in the most recent version of Notepad++. Make sure you click on the character in the character column, not the Value or Hex. Otherwise, check the encoding of your file.

Comment: @mbomb007 Absolutely correct! I'm sure I must have been clicking different columns and not noticing a distinction. The UI really should have a grid look if the different columns do different things, but c'est la vie.

Answer (score 14):

**With Notepad++**

**From HEX**

1. Type 00 00 00
2. Select this text
3. TextFX > TextFX Convert > Convert Hex to text

**From Base64**

1. Type AA==
2. Select this text
3. Plugins > MIME Tools > Base64 Decode

The mapping is:

```
NUL -> AA=
NUL NUL -> AAA=
NUL NUL NUL -> AAAA
```

Comment: Your steps don't match your mappings. You say `AA==` in one place and `AA=` in another.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. The OP is using Notepad.

Comment: @DavidPostill The OP asked for something that is impossible, so it's fine that he provide an alternative method of entering a NUL into a file.

Answer (score 6):

Normal text editors such as Notepad usually do not have the capability to enter NUL characters into files. What you probably want to do is to use a ["hex editor"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor) (some text editors also have a "hex" mode). This will let you enter NUL characters, or any other byte you might need.