# Replace given char with ASCII nul in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I tried extended search --> replace with `\0`, but it does not seem to work. Instead it deletes all occurrences of the character. Could it be a bug?

NB: replacing with `\n`, `\r\n` and the like works in extended search.

I am using Notepad++ 6.4.1 Unicode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reported it as a bug [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/4542/) - please comment there in hope it's fixed - looks like a possible can of worms to me.

References :

- [How to find, replace and highlight text in Notepad++](https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Searching_And_Replacing#Escape_sequences_supported_in_extended_mode)
- [How to Insert a Null Character (ASCII 00) in Notepad?](https://superuser.com/questions/61742/insert-a-null-character-ascii-00-in-notepad)

Answer (score 1):

Try `\d###` (where # is a single digit in the 0-9 range).

See [Escape sequences supported in extended mode](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Searching_And_Replacing#Escape_sequences_supported_in_extended_mode) for more.

**Edit:** Looks like \d, \u, \x etc. don't work properly when it comes to replacing with the `NUL` character. Search works fine (I inserted a few `NUL`s using a hex editor), but replace doesn't and simply deletes the characters.

Comment: sounds like bug report time then :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Notepad++ has always had issues with inserting 0-characters.
Notepad++ is no exception: Most editors can't deal properly with it.
It is not really surprising. Dealing with 0-characters is quite a niche application.

The only Windows editor that I am aware of that can handle 0's as any other character is UltraEdit.
(And it has an hex-edit mode as well, so one way or another you can get the job done with it.)

Answer (score 1):

Searches on the internet showed that inserting **NUL** in Notepad++ is non-trivial, for example see [How to Insert a Null Character (ASCII 00) in Notepad?](https://superuser.com/questions/61742/insert-a-null-character-ascii-00-in-notepad)

A hackish way to replace given character/characters with **NUL** is via the [Hex Editor Plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/Hex%20Editor/)<sup>†</sup>.

1. Go to hex mode (via Plugins → HEX-Editor → View in HEX, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
2. Highlight the character(s) you want to replace.

   - You can either highlight it in the "Dump" column or in the "0 | 1 | ... | f" column.
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the Replace menu.

   - Change "Data type" to "Hexadecimal".
   - The character(s) you highlighted will show up under "Find what" (as a hex string)
   - Enter "00" in the "Replace with" field (that is a null byte)
4. Press "Replace" or "Replace all".

Disclaimer: I've heard from somewhere that the Hex Editor plugin is buggy but I've only used it occasionally in the past (it worked alright but your mileage may vary) so I don't really know the extent of its bugginess.

<sup>†</sup> <sub>You can install it via Notepad++'s Plugin Manager (Plugins → Plugin Manager → Show Plugin Manager) but you might need to check "Show unstable plugins" under Plugin Manager's "Settings" for the plugin to show up</sub>

Comment: I found this same plugin while searching, and uninstalled it after it crashed my NP++ twice. Instead I just used a good ol' hex editor instead.

Comment: @Karan, it rarely crashed when I was using it. I should probably add a "YMMV" disclaimer to my answer.

Comment: lol it hangs on ctrl+h - but yeah that's a step to the right direction - could you fill a bug report and post it here ? edit : I'd seen the question you ;inked to (I did search before asking but did not work anyway - and I need a replace not an insert)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: If you're asking him to report bugs in the plugin, won't help. That plugin seems to have been been abandoned for the last 4 years or so.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: can't really reproduce that. Do you have a large file or something? How about you try Ctrl+F then click on "Replace" tab (i.e. try random stuff)

Comment: no it's a normal file ~ 8kb. Ctrl-F hangs just the same - hmmm - I have `\n` line endings - but no, on other files with `\r\n` is the same

Answer (score 0):

#### How to insert any byte value into a text:

1. `Npp` -> `Plugins` -> `Python Script` -> `New Script`
2. Select where to save ... and give the name `insert a byte` (say)
3. in opened Npp doc insert this code:

   ```
       s= notepad.prompt('Enter value, or series, in a box, e.g.: \x5Cx00 ','Insert a byte ')
       exec("a=b'{}'".format(s))
       editor.addText(a)
   ```
4. `Save`.
5. Restart `Npp`
6. Then you must see own script under menu:
   `Npp` -> `Plugins` -> `Python Script` -> `Script` -> `insert a byte`
7. If you want shortcut for this, please see how to: 
   [Wrap Text with Quotation Marks in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11784510/1560228)